# CloudKit - Can't retrieve the data from iCloud

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

Is there any difference in sending and receiving data from iCloud via `CloudKit` when the application (iOS9) runs through Xcode or when it is downloaded from the App Store?

My problem is: Application launched from Xcode receives and displays data successfully, the same app published in the App Store can not display the data...

In what could be the mistake?

Thank you.

```
func getRecordsFromCloud() {
        // Fetch data using Convenience API
        let cloudContainer = CKContainer.defaultContainer()
        let publicDatabase = cloudContainer.publicCloudDatabase
        let predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
        let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Pivo", predicate: predicate)
        query.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)]

        // Create the query operation with the query
        let queryOperation = CKQueryOperation(query: query)
        queryOperation.desiredKeys = ["name", "type", "location"]
        queryOperation.queuePriority = .VeryHigh
        queryOperation.resultsLimit = 50
        queryOperation.recordFetchedBlock = { (record:CKRecord!) -> Void in
            if let restaurantRecord = record {
                self.restaurants.append(restaurantRecord)
            }
        }

        queryOperation.queryCompletionBlock = { (cursor:CKQueryCursor?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
            if (error != nil) {
                print("Failed to get data from iCloud - \(error!.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }

            print("Successfully retrieve the data from iCloud")
            self.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
            NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock() {
                self.spinner.stopAnimating()
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }

        }

        // Execute the query
        publicDatabase.addOperation(queryOperation)
    }
```

Comment: Did you migrate your development environment to production using the cloudkit dashboard?

Comment: I totally forgot about it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to migrate your development environment to production using the CloudKit dashboard

Comment: One question... The public database is working well. What about the private database? Now I don't have to do nothing more in CloudKit Dashboard?